# How does one perform an infinite series expansion of a function "at" infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Question speaks for itself.

Ive seen it suggested that we substitute $x$ for $\dfrac{1}{x}$, and expand $f(\dfrac1x)$ about $0$. But the problem is, this isnt always possible, I dont think.

There is an infinite series expansion of $\arctan(x)$ at infinity that Wolfram|Alpha offers up, but when you ask it to expand $\arctan(1/x)$ at $0$, it bugs up and doesnt produce.

So Im confused about the actual approach to determining such a series.

Similar questions have been asked on SE but none ask explicitly on **how**.  Answers given to those questions also dont elaborate on any method.  Ive also seen reference to Laurent series and Asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Im not familiar with Laurent series. A Wikipeida/Google search turned up closed line integrals on a complex plane.  Also, I did point out that $\arctan(x)$ **does** have an expansion at infinity (provided by Wolfram|Alpha) despite the fact that $\arctan(1/x)$ being discontinuous at $x=0$ **and** Wolfram|Alpha not being able to produce an expansion for $\arctan(1/x)$.  How does Wolfram produce an expansion at infinity for $\arctan(x)$ if it cannot produce one at $x=0$ for $\arctan(1/x)$ ?  In any case, my question is HOW, and thats still been unanswered.

Comment: What about $\begin{cases}\arctan \frac1x&x>0\\\arctan \frac 1x+\pi &x<0\end{cases}$?

Comment: See a complex analysis course, we use the Cauchy integral formula on an annulus to find the Laurent series of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

- Iff $f(1/z)$ is **complex analytic** on $0<|z|<r$ there is a Laurent series expansion of $f$ at $\infty$. Most other kind of expansions are obtained the same way, from $f(1/g(z))$ or from a sequence of analytic functions approximating $f$.
- For $|z| < 1$ : $2i\text{ arctan}'(z) = \frac{2i}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{1}{z-i}$ so $2i\text{ arctan}(z)  = \log(z+i)-\log(z-i)$. But there are *many possible branches for $\log(z+i)$ and $\log(z-i)$*.Choosing the branch cut to be $[-i, i]$ it is analytic for $|z| > 1$ and hence has a Laurent series at $\infty$ valid for $|z| > 1$. But obviously mathematica implements $\text{ arctan}(z)$ as being analytic on $|z| < 1$, in this setting the branch cut is $[i,i\infty) \cup [-i,-i\infty)$ so that $\text{ arctan}(z)$ is **not** analytic on $|z| > 1$ and hence has no Laurent series at $\infty$.
- If $g$ is complex analytic on $r-a< |z| < r+b$ and if you like Fourier series, then compute the Fourier coefficients to obtain $$g(r e^{2i \pi n t}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2i \pi n t}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{r^n} r^n e^{2i \pi n t}$$
  since $g$ is complex analytic, this series is valid for $t$ complex, ie. you'll obtain that for $r-a< |z| < r+b$

  $$g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{r^n} z^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that Wolfram|Alpha is free to use and hence also limited in its functionality. If you were to use Mathematica, it would have had no problems with a series expansion of the form "Series[ArcTan[1/x],{x,0,10}]" and it would give you the same result as the expansion at infinity (Series[ArcTan[x],{x,0,10}]). There would only be a slight difference, which has to do with the fact that Mathematica treats the variable $x$ as a complex number, but that could be solved without to much difficulty.

So how to do the expansion of a function $f(1/x)$ in the limit $x \rightarrow 0$? It is not as difficult as it seems. You can make a Taylor expansion of the function at $x=a>0$ in some small parameter $\epsilon$
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{a+\epsilon}\right) \approx f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) + f'\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) \epsilon + \frac{1}{2} f''\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) \epsilon^2 + {\cal O}(\epsilon^3)
$$
For this we only need to compute the various derivatives of the function we have and it would be a correct Taylor expansion at any location $x=a>0$. If we now take the limit $a \downarrow 0$ we get an expansion:
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right) \approx  \lim_{a \downarrow 0} \left\{f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) + f'\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) \epsilon + \frac{1}{2} f''\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) \epsilon^2 + {\cal O}(\epsilon^3) \right\}  \epsilon^2 + \dots
$$
Since we want to know the limiting behaviour of $f(x)$ for large $x$ we make the identification $x=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $b=\frac{1}{a}$ and get that for large $x$ the expansion takes the form
$$
f\left(x\right) \approx  \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left\{f\left(b\right) + \frac{f'\left(b\right)}{x} + \frac{f''\left(b\right)}{2 x^2} + {\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \right\} \\
= f\left(\infty\right) + \frac{f'\left(\infty\right)}{x}  + \frac{f''\left(\infty\right)}{2 x^2}  + \dots
$$
So we sort of compute the derivatives at infinity.

I have to stress that I show here an incomplete and simplified explanation to illustrate the idea of how such expansion can be obtained and hope this answers your question. I have not justified exchanging limits, shown convergence, or mentioned the problems with complex branches and various other issues that would need to be addressed in a proper proof.